# Is [cleaning] a meta tag?

Tags: discussion

Is [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) a meta tag? The wiki says it is ambiguous and must be used with other tags. Doesn't this mean it's a meta tag? Or is the wiki incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

The wiki means that the tag is about cleaning and since cleaning is a broad term, since you can clean a lot of things to add another tag. This is to show that you in the [kitchen](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen)  and you are [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning).

The Tag said this:

> Cleaning is the act of making (something or someone) free of dirt,
>   marks, or mess, especially by washing, wiping, or brushing.
>
> THIS TAG IS AMBIGUOUS: please also use another applicable tag. (e.g.,
>   [clothing], [kitchen], etc.)

I think the tag is necessary as it indicates what you want to do in the kitchen or bathroom. If it was removed finding questions would be harder, because then you would be in the [kitchen](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen) and what you wanted to do wouldn't be known. Could this tag be phrased better? Yes, it probably could be.

***I do not think this tag is a meta tag within my knowledge of what a meta tag is.***